# Alternatives of BitThief to Download Torrent Files Sequentially

Tags: torrent

I have reasons to modify my Java 6 (legacy) runtime resulting at the torrent client BitThief failed to run. I didn't like the application anyways so I am looking for an alternative. I did a Google search and found a few torrent clients on OSX that supports sequential download but I still like to get some experienced opinions. What I am looking for is a less resource intensive and stable client. Thanks.

PS. I am running OSX 10.10.2.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Transmission (https://www.transmissionbt.com/). Best BitTorrent client on Mac. 
There is no sequential download option, but you don't want that, it is not only damaging to the BitTorrent network, but downloading sequentially also should result in slower download speed for you in general.

If it is about streaming the videos you download, aka start watching while downloading, give Popcorn Time a try. It is a streaming client based on the BT protocol and works nicely.